# Multiplying hours/minutes in a calculated column

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column-formula

I am trying to use calculated columns to sum the difference between two times then multiply that result by a number.

The SharePoint list looks like this:

[image]

The "Start Time" and "End Time" columns are TEXT, the reason for this is because the list is being populated from Microsoft Form, which doesn't have a native time control so users are inputting this as free text.

"Time Diff" is a calculated column with the following calculation

```
=TEXT([Start Time]-[End Time],"h:mm")
```

This appears to be working as expected and is showing the time difference between the two time fields.

The next step is I want to multiply the result in "Time Diff" by the number in "Employee Count".  Again this is a calculated column with the following formula

```
=[Time Diff]*[Employee Count]*24
```

As you can see it is working where the "Employee Count" is 2, but if it is 1 the sum isn't correct, the "Calculated Total Time" and "Time Diff" column should be the same.  I am frustratingly close but I can't see to get this sum right, hopefully someone will be able to help?

Thanks in advance
Rob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to achieve the goal with this formula:

```
=CONCATENATE(INT([Time Diff]*[Employee Count]*24),":",TEXT(MOD([Time Diff]*[Employee Count]*24*60, 60), "00"))
```

Comment: We posted our answers at the same time, your solution is very neat - thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I can see the issue was between the seat and keyboard here.  The "Calculated Total Time" is of course the decimal of the time, so 45 minutes = 0.75 of an hour so that calculation is correct.

Rob